# Dagger @Singleton in object module

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I have a question if there is any significal difference between using `@Module` object without `@Singleton` functions and `@Module` class with `@Singleton` functions.

So like:

```
@Module
object ApiModule {

    @Provides
    fun test()
}
```

```
@Module
class ApiModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun test()
}
```

Do I have to mark `@Singleton` in `object` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Dagger being an Annotation Processor often the simplest and easiest solution is to just have a look at the generated code.

I prepared a *minimal* sample to demonstrate:

```
class Foo()
class Bar()

@Component(modules = [ClassModule::class, ObjectModule::class])
interface FooComponent {

    val foo: Foo
    val bar: Bar
}

@Module
class ClassModule {

    @Provides
    fun foo() = Foo()
}

@Module
object ObjectModule {

    @Provides
    fun bar() = Bar()
}
```

If we take a look at the generated code we can see the following (I removed some irrelevant bits, just compile the above code yourself and look at the implementation if you want to see it all)

```
public final class DaggerFooComponent implements FooComponent {
  private final ClassModule classModule;

  private DaggerFooComponent(ClassModule classModuleParam) {
    this.classModule = classModuleParam;
  }

  public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
  }

  @Override
  public Foo getFoo() {
    return ClassModule_FooFactory.foo(classModule);}

  @Override
  public Bar getBar() {
    return ObjectModule_BarFactory.bar();}

  public static final class Builder {
    private ClassModule classModule;

    private Builder() {
    }

    public Builder classModule(ClassModule classModule) {
      this.classModule = Preconditions.checkNotNull(classModule);
      return this;
    }

    public FooComponent build() {
      if (classModule == null) {
        this.classModule = new ClassModule();
      }
      return new DaggerFooComponent(classModule);
    }
  }
}
```

What you will notice is that Dagger creates an object for `ClassModule`, but uses `ObjectModule` with its static method directly. Does this matter? Well, creating a new object is *slow*, not so much that it really matters, but we don't need to reduce performance unnecessarily either. So if you can, you should definitely prefer `object` or `interface` as modules for better performance.

As for the scope, it really doesn't matter what your modules look like, it's the method signature that counts. Dagger looks at the *return type* of the method along with any annotation to it. So yes, of course you need to set a scope no matter what you use for your module, `object`, `class`, or `interface`. *Ideally you'd add the scope on the class itself, though, and use constructor injection to avoid modules altogether.*

---

***tl;dr*** `class` Modules result in an additional object being created, so `interface` or `object` modules should be preferred if possible.

Comment: Cool very clear and awesome answer. Thank you for Your time and effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes if don't have @Singlton then the function will be invoked once for each time you need to inject whatever test returns. If you have @Singleton the return value will be cached by dagger and reused each time it's needed.